# The tangent space to an affine variety has a "local formulation".

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I am studying the chapter 10 (Smooth Varieties) in Gathmann's lecture notes on Algebraic Geometry and there are several things that I don't understand. Let me recall the context.

He defined the *tangent space* as follows.

> **Definition 10.1** Let $a$ be a point on a variety $X$. By choosing an affine neighborhood of $a$ we assume that $X \subset \mathbb A^n$ and that $a = 0$ is the origin, so that no polynomial $f \in I(X)$ has constant term. Then
> $$T_aX = V(f_1:f \in I(X)) \subset \mathbb A^n$$
> is called the **tangent space** of $X$ at $a$, where $f \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ denotes the linear term of a polynomial $f \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

He said as a remark that in this definition we made a choice of the affine variety $X$ such that $a = 0$ and in fact this definition does not depend on this choice. To show this statement, he proves the following lemmas.

> **Lemma 10.4** Let $X \subset \mathbb A^n$ be an affine variety containing the origin $a = 0$, whose ideal is then $I(a) = \langle\overline{x_1}, \ldots, \overline{x_n} \rangle\trianglelefteq A(X)$ (the coordinate ring). Then there is a natural vector space isomorphism
> $$I(a)/I(a)^2 \cong \text{Hom}_K(T_aX, K).$$
> In other words, the tangent space $T_a X$ is naturally the vector space dual to $I(a)/I(a)^2.$

And then

> **Corollary 10.5** For $S = A(X)\backslash I(X)$, we have
> $$I(a)/I(a)^2 \cong (S^{-1} I(a))/(S^{-1}I(a))^2.$$
> In particular, if $a \in X$ is a point on any variety $X$ and $I_a~(\cong S^{-1} I(a))$ is the unique maximal ideal in $\mathcal O_{X, a}$ (which is the *stalk* at $a$ of $\mathcal O_X$ isomorphic to $S^{-1}A(X)$), then $T_aX$ is naturally isomorphic to the vector space dual to $I_a/I_a^2$ and thus independent of any choice.

First, for $a \in X$ we can always suppose that $X$ is an affine variety by definition of a variety but why can we suppose that $a = 0$? Then I am not very sure to understand the explanation why $T_aX$ has a "local formulation". Why the corollary 10.5 does only depends on $a$ and on nothing else? I am not very comfortable with this explanation so if one of you could talk a bit more about that it would be very nice!

Comment: You can suppose $a=0$ by applying the automorphism $\mathbb A^n \to \mathbb A^n$ given by $x \mapsto x-a$. You never indicate what exactly is meant by "local formulation" in your post, but I think the upshot is that since the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,a}$ is independent of any choice of affine chart, anything that can be computed purely in terms of the local ring is similarly so independent. And of course $T_a X$ is such a thing, but it occurs to me that writing $I(a) = \langle \bar{x_1},...,\bar{x_n}\rangle$ is potentially confusion since the $n$ generators are not independent in $A(X)$...

Comment: ...rather, $I(a)$ is independent of the affine embedding, meaning that if $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ and $k[y_1,...,y_m]/J$ are isomorphic rings corresponding to different affine embeddings of the same variety, then a particular isomorphism $\phi$ will induce an isomorphism between $\langle \bar{x_1},...,\bar{x_n}\rangle$ and $\langle \bar{y_1},...,\bar{y_m}\rangle$.

Comment: This doesn't change anything in my comments, but there is a small typo that the poster below caught: in the Corollary, you should begin $S = A(X) \setminus I(a)$, otherwise you don't get anything interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "First, for a∈X we can always suppose that X is an affine variety by definition of a variety but why can we suppose that a=0? Then I am not very sure to understand the explanation why TaX has a "local formulation". Why the corollary 10.5 does only depends on a and on nothing else? I am not very comfortable with this explanation so if one of you could talk a bit more about that it would be very nice!"

**Answer:** To fully understand your question, you must include some definitions. Different authors use different definitions.

If $k$ is an algebraically closed field and if $a:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is the polynomial ring in $n$ variables with $I\subseteq A$ an ideal, let $X:=V(I)$ be defined as follows:

$$V(I):=\{a\in k^n:f(a)=0\text{ for all }f\in I\}.$$

If $a:=(a_1,..,a_n)\in X$ there is an automorphism $\phi_a$ of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ defined as follows:

$$\phi_a(x_i):=x_i-a_i.$$

Let $\mathfrak{m}_a:=(x_i-a_i)$ be the maximal ideal corresponding to $a$.

It follows $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{m}_a)=(x_1,..,x_n):=\mathfrak{m}_0$. The automorphism

$$\phi_a: \mathbb{A}^n_k \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_k$$

maps $a:=(a_1,..,a_n)$ to the origin $0:=(0,..,0)$. When we restrict $\phi_a$ to $X$ we get an induced isomorphism

$$\phi_a: X \rightarrow \phi_a(X):=Y$$

mapping $a$ to the origin $0$. The tangent space is intrinsic hence is unchanged under isomorphisms. Hence we may study the tangent space of $Y$ at the origin $0$.

**Remark:** You should include more details where you take care about the notation since it seems your notation is not correct. What you must specify is the following: In the language of Hartshorne, Chapter I, if $X \subseteq k^n$ is an algebraic variety, there is a prime ideal $I(X) \subseteq k[x_1,..,x_n]$ where $I(X)$ is the ideal of functions vanishing at $X$. We define the coordinate ring $A(X)$ of $X$ as follows: $A(X):=k[x_1,..,x_n]/I(X)$. When you write $S:=A(X)-I(X)$ with this definition it follows $I(X)=(0)$ is the zero ideal hence $S$ is the set of all non-zero elements in $A(X)$. Then you choose a "point" $a\in X$ with ideal $I_a$ and localize at $S$ and claim there is an isomorphism

$$ I_a \cong S^{-1}I_a.$$

What you are doing here seems to be to pass to the quotient field $K(X):=A(X)_{(0)}$.  And there are no non-trivial ideals in $K(X)$ since $K(X)$ is a field, hence $S^{-1}I_a=(1)=K(X)$.
What you must do is to explain this construction more closely. It is not clear what you are speaking about.

PS: If you look at Hartshorne, Exercise I.7.4 there is an elementary exercise where you speak of the tangent line and the dual curve of a plane projective curve. This exercise is instructive. There is also an intuitive explanation in Mumfords "the red book...".

As mentioned in the comments: The tangent space and cotangent space depends only on the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ of $X$ at $x$ and is invariant under isomorphism. Under the automorphism $\phi_a$ above we get an induced isomorphism of local rings

$$ \mathcal{O}_{X,a} \cong \mathcal{O}_{Y,0}$$

where $0\in Y$ is the origin. This induce an isomorphism of vector spaces

$$T_aX \cong T_0Y.$$

In general if $i:U \rightarrow X$ is an open subvariety with $x\in U$ is follows

$$\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U,x}$$

is an isomorphism of local rings, hence you may always choose an affine open subvariety $U:=Spec(B)$ containing $x$ when making calculations.

**Example - affine schemes:** If you are familiar with affine schemes this example may be an explanation of Corr 10.5: If $X:=Spec(B)$ and if $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq B$ is a prime ideal and $f\in B$ with $f\notin \mathfrak{p}$. Let $x\in X$ be the point corresponding to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. There is an isomorphism of local rings

$$L1.\text{  } (B_f)_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong B_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$

Let $U:=D(f):=Spec(B_f)$. At the level of local rings you get from $L1$ an isomorphism of local rings

$$ \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{U,x}$$

The ring $\mathcal{O}_{U,x}\cong B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}(x):=\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and you may define the tangent space $T_xX$ as follows:

$$T_xX:=Hom_{\kappa(x)}(\mathfrak{m}(x)/\mathfrak{m}(x)^2, \kappa(x)).$$

When $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal it follows $\kappa(x)\cong k$. I believe there is an intuitive explanation of the geometric meaning of the tangent space at non-closed points in the reference I gave above.

This definition seems unintuitive and abstract to someone not familiar with this construction but it is the correct definition - again I believe "The red book.." gives a good intuitive explanation why this is the correct definition.

Comment: What issues do you take with OP's notation? It looks like it was all copied from Gathmann's notes which tend to be pretty reliable. Also, this doesn't really answer the question; OP is not studying a fixed affine variety in a particular affine space, but an arbitrary chart on an arbitrary variety, and the main issue is showing independence of affine presentation (possibly in spaces of different dimension).

Comment: If you're going to complain about the OP not including their definitions or more details, why not ask them to do that in a comment before writing an answer?

Comment: @hm2020 I'm referring to your claim "it seems your notation is not correct," not your request for definitions.

Comment: Ah. Again, I would encourage you to comment in a less sanctimonious tone. Gathmann's/OP's notation is not lacking or incorrect, OP simply copied a single letter down incorrectly: $S$ is meant to be the complement of $I(a)$ in $S(X)$, not the complement of $I(X)$. And given that OP was trying to restrict things to the point $a$, this was basically clear from context.

Comment: @TabesBridges - If you take a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ and let $S:=A-\mathfrak{p}$, there is in general no isomorphism $\mathfrak{p} \cong S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ - hence your claim does not make any sense. You are yourself referring to $S(X)$ - this notation is not mentioned in the above post. When posting a question it is important that the asker includes all definitions in the post - in this case it seems the notation is a bit "non standard".

Comment: @hm2020 No one has claimed that those ideals are isomorphic, just certain quotients (the cotangent spaces). When I wrote $S(X)$ I meant simply to refer to the multiplicative closed set $S = A(X) - I(a)$. And again, I don't know how long you've been studying algebraic geometry, but Gathmann's notes are at this point a venerated and easily accessible (for free online) source; they are one of a handful of sources which I (and most frequent commenters under the algebraic-geometry tag) don't mind looking up. The notation isn't really odd unless you are wedded to Hartshorne's conventions.